# Mongodb node.js driver upgrade to 2.0.27 returns result differently for collection.save

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have upgraded my mongodb driver to 2.0.27 (it used to be 1.4.29), I work against several environments: 2.4, 2.6 and 3.0, for 2.4 and 3.0 it works well, but when I run it against 2.6 I can different results when calling:
`this.collection.save(account, {}, function (err, result){...});`
on 2.4 I'm getting only my account doc, but on 2.6 I'm getting:

```
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
connection: 
{ domain: null,
_events: 
{ close: [Object],
error: [Object],
timeout: [Object],
parseError: [Object],
connect: [Function] },
_maxListeners: 10,
..... },
ops: 
[ { profile: {},
type: 'individual',
created_at: Thu Apr 16 2015 13:07:11 GMT+0000 (UTC),
identities: [],
_id: 552fb3ffea521d3c1d5a93ee } ] }
```

I'm still getting the new doc but under ops, and not as before.

Is this a bug with the new mongodb driver? Should I work differently with my result? How come I get different results from different db versions?

Comment: That response is [documented here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~WriteOpResult) (`WriteOpResultObject`).

Comment: thanks. can I control it? can i get the result in the old format? because my code isn't expecting it as the new format is?

Comment: From a quick glance it doesn't look like you can configure it. But perhaps `result = Array.isArray(result.result) ? result.result : result` may be a quick fix?